# How can you access a private function from a friend function in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

Can anyone tell me how to call a private function of a class from a friend function of that class

Answer (score 3):

Like you would a private data member. Just access it:

```
class A
{
  void foo() {}     // private member function
  friend void bar();
};

void bar() {
    A a;
    a.foo(); // access A's privates
}
```

Comment: @NolwennLeGuen oh, people will know what to do...